# Error - Call to undefined function yaml_parse_file()

Tags: php, yaml

My friend has used yaml in a shared project. I tried to follow her instructions but got stuck at:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function yaml_parse_file() in /var/www/html/cdn/map_of_site.php on line 8

So I thought that I should install the Yaml library (which I think I did correctly).
I also added the Yaml parser in the php.ini
But the error continues to appear.

The worst part is that I won't be able to get in touch with her for a couple of days (and I kind of dislike telling her that I don't know how to make her code work).

Could you please tell me in general what is required to make a project that uses `yaml_parse_file()` function work? Like what should I install or where to install it ...

PS: I work with Linux mint and the project is PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I hadn't installed yaml correctly. This  article and the instructions that linux itself gives (<3) helped me solve it:

https://code.google.com/p/php-yaml/wiki/InstallingWithPecl

Answer (score 0):

Your frend used a php module that you don't have installed or enabled.
You can try to install it in the regular way (I don't know linux mint myself):
- apt-get install php5-yaml
- yum install php5-yaml
Or something like that.

If yaml is not available like that, you can try to use pecl.
You need this package: http://pecl.php.net/package/yaml

If you have pecl installed on your system (apt-get install pecl), you can just do pecl install yaml.

Usually when the extension is installed it is also directly enabled. You can test if it is enabled by creating a php file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it and running or visiting it (then search for yaml).